# C# Quiz Using Access Database Problem

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am attempting to create a quiz for my C# program using an Access database to hold the question and answers.
In the database table, the questions are in one column, and the answers are in another column. In essence, this is what I would like to happen:

The form loads, and as this happens a question randomly chosen from the database appears on that form. The question itself will be displayed using the label.

Here is my code:

```
private void WindowsAnalysisQuiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare connection string using windows security
        string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\\\WindowsAnalysisQuiz.accdb";

        //declare Connection, command and other related objects
        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

        try
        {
            //open connection
            conGet.Open();

            cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdGet.Connection = conGet;
            cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT Question FROM WindowsAnalysisQuiz ORDER BY rand()";

            label1.Text = cmdGet.CommandText["Question"];

            conGet.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //display generic error message back to user
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //check if connection is still open then attempt to close it
            if (conGet.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conGet.Close();
            }
        }

    }

   }
```

I am getting a problem at the point where I am trying to assign a random question to be displayed in my label. 
As an aside, is this method of using a database to store the questions and answers doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function you mean is rnd(), not rand().

but i´m not sure if this is possible via the oledb driver.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have an Autonumber field in your questions table. Then you can generate the random value in your code, and then query based on the randomly chosen ID number. If, for instance, your questions were numbered 1 to 100, you'd limit the range of your generated random number to that range.